# Concatenation with arrays in C++ again?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    while(destination[counter2] != '/0'){
        counter2++;
    }

    while(source[counter] != '/0'){
        destination[counter2 - 1 + counter] = source[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    destination[counter] += '/0';
}

int main(){

}
```

For my edited code, the school test bed says that it is taking too long and crashes.  I am to concatenate source to destination.  Before I do that, I have to replace the last element of destination (which will be '/0') with the first element of source then add '/0' to the end of source.  For destination, it has to be large enough to hold the concatenated string.

Edit:

```
void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    while(destination[counter2] != '/0'){
        counter2++;
    }

    while(source[counter] != '\0'){
        destination[counter2 - 1 + counter] = source[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    destination[counter] += '\0';
}

int main(){

}
```

I'm still having problems with this code.  Test bed says that it is taking too long and crashes.

edit3:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    while(destination[counter2] != '\0'){
        counter2++;
    }

    while(source[counter] != '\0'){
        destination[counter2 + counter] = source[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    destination[counter2 + counter] += '\0';

}

int main(){
}
```

It still says that it is producing an incorrect result.

Comment: why `destination[counter2 + counter] += '\0';` when it should be `destination[counter2 + counter] = '\0';`

Comment: And `destination[counter] += '\0';` doesn't assign `'\0'` (or `NULL`) and also doesn't change value of `destination[counter]`. Therefore, unless `destination[counter]` is `NULL`, your string would most likely heading nowhere. In this case, if the rest of `destination` array doesn't have any `NULL` character, accessing it as a string takes long time since it looks for `NULL` character at index out of bound of `destination` array, and hasn't found one yet. Otherwise, your app might crash due to modification at these indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(destination[counter] != '/0'){
    counter2++;
}
```

Either use `counter` or `counter2` in this loop. Otherwise it will never end!

I would imagine you need

```
while(destination[counter2] != '\0'){
    counter2++;
}
```

**EDIT2**

Just noticed - You need '\0' not '/0'

Comment: After revising it, it is still saying that it is taking too long and crashes.

Comment: @user3024476 - Please do not edit the question like that - the answers/comments stop making sense. Just append an update.

Comment: `while(destination[counter2] != '/0'){` should be `while(destination[counter2] != '\0'){`

Comment: now the test harness says that it is giving an incorrect result but at least it is a start.

Comment: @user3024476 - Get a print out and a piece of paper and go through each step in turn (or use a debugger)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Make sure the destination is big enough to hold source!

void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    while(destination[counter2] != '\0') counter2++;
    while(source[counter] != '\0') counter++;

    memmove(destination+counter2, source, counter);
    destination[counter+counter2] = '\0';
}
```

or

```
void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    strcat(destination, source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    // This loop looks like it will work. We will exit when destination[counter2] ==   '\0'. Just change '/0' to '\0'.
    while(destination[counter2] != '/0'){
        counter2++;                                 
    }

    // I think you should change destination[counter2 - 1 + counter], to destination[counter2 + counter]. That way you overwrite the null char in destination, as you would want.
    while(source[counter] != '\0'){
        destination[counter2 - 1 + counter] = source[counter];
        counter++;
    }

    // Uhh, change this to destination[counter + counter2] = '\0'.
    destination[counter] += '\0';
}
```

Assuming destination is large enough, that shouldn't crash. As for it taking too long, I don't see why it would, unless you're under very strict timing.

Comment: I edited my code but it still says that it is giving an incorrect result.  Not sure where could be the problem though.

Comment: probably the **+=** '\0';

Comment: Remove the '+=' and replace it with '='.

Comment: It finally works.  Thank you all for your assistance.  I'm going through this right now for studying.